# How to add a calendar filled with bookings to the website of a pension?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, calendar

I wan't to add a calendar to my webpage, in which the guests would see which dates are still free and whichones are already booked, so they can plan their vacation after that. How can I manage this?

I made a HTML webpage, and I tried to do something like the calendar on AirBnB

Answer (score 1):

Go to your calendar and select Settings and Sharing as shown below.

[image]

Then look for this dialog.

[image]

Use the embed code to embed calendar into website.  It's already within it's own iFrame.